# Restrict Items to Admin Role & User Role Membership Provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-membership

Here i wanted to check if userRole is Administrator then shows all the menu items & if userRole is other than administrator then shows the public menu items.But here there's no any error but its shows samething to Admin & Normal User

```
 <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
 <ul class="nav"> 
     <%if (Roles.IsUserInRole(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name, "Administrator"))
     {%>
<li class="active"><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li>

<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Company <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul aria-labelledby="dLabel" role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
            <a href="CompanyProfile.aspx">Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="FileData.aspx">FileData</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>

<%}
 else
  { %>
<li class="active"><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li>

<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Company <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul aria-labelledby="dLabel" role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
            <a href="CompanyProfile.aspx">Profile</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>

<% }    
%>
</ul>
</div>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: And when the User.Identity.Name is a normal user what value contains? are you sure that the normal user is in a different role than administrator?, if the menu is only available for administrator users I will only check for the role <%if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Administrator"))

Answer (score 1):

For that kind of scenario, you want to use [LoginView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control instead of hard coding C# class inside html markup which is really fragile and hard to maintain.

Besides, if Membership is configured correctly in your application, LoginView control will work correctly right out of the box.

```
<asp:LoginView id="LoginView1" runat="server">
   <AnonymousTemplate>
      Please log in for personalized information.
   </AnonymousTemplate>
   <LoggedInTemplate>
     Thanks for logging in 
      <asp:LoginName id="LoginName1" runat="Server"></asp:LoginName>.
   </LoggedInTemplate>
   <RoleGroups>
      <asp:RoleGroup Roles="Administrator">
         <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
               <ul class="nav"> 
                  <li class="active"><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
                   ....
                </ul>
             </div>
         </ContentTemplate>
      </asp:RoleGroup>
   </RoleGroups>
</asp:LoginView>
```